# SAML spec: returning to the SP without a user

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

I'm using the standard [SAML 2.0 SP-initiated SSO](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.html#5.1.2.SP-Initiated%20SSO:%20%20Redirect/POST%20Bindings%7Coutline) protocol for authentication.

Normally the IdP returns a `samlp:Response` XML object to my SP, containing a `saml:Assertion` about the authenticated user.

Does the SAML spec allow the IdP to return a response to the SP that doesn't contain user information?

I'd like handle the situation where authentication couldn't be done, but we want to return to the SP's site. Maybe the IdP could return some kind of error or message to our SP? Right now it seems like if authentication is impossible, the user is stuck on the IdP's site.

I guess they could just redirect to an agreed-upon URL, although then you would lose the RelayState information. Would that be the right approach, or does the SAML spec handle this scenario?

Comment: The closest I've found so far is [this](https://docops.ca.com/ca-single-sign-on/12-52-sp1/en/configuring/partnership-federation/saml-2-0-feature-configuration/configure-a-saml-2-0-response-for-authentication-failure), which is specific to one product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAML2 spec handles this. The Idp can return a `samlp:response` with a status code of `Responder` meaning that the idp failed to fulfill the request. Then there can be more detailed status information on exactly why.

But the case where an Idp fails to authenticate the user can be handled in the protocol. However, I think that most Idps behave as you describe - keep the user on the Idp if things goes wrong.

Added by OP — this is from the [SAML spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf):

> `<StatusCode>` [Optional]
>
> A subordinate status code that provides more specific information on an error condition. Note that responders MAY omit subordinate status codes in order to prevent attacks that seek to probe for additional information by intentionally presenting erroneous requests.
>
> The permissible top-level  values are as follows:
>
> `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success`
>   The request succeeded. Additional information MAY be returned in the  and/or  elements.
>
> `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester`
>   The request could not be performed due to an error on the part of the requester.
>
> `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder`
>   The request could not be performed due to an error on the part of the SAML responder or SAML authority.
>
> `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:VersionMismatch`
>   The SAML responder could not process the request because the version of the request message was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! That wasn't easy to find.